# Use :nth-child and :nth-last-child in one selection

Tags: html, css

I am looking to select some `div's` using `:nth-child()` and `:nth-last-child()`.

But im not getting past this:

First i select all `div's` doing this: `.align div:nth-child(n)`, after that i don't want all of the `div's` selected so im using `:nth-child(odd)` and in the end 
I have 2 `div's` i don't want to select so im using `:nth-last-child(2)` to filter them out.

The full code will look like this:

```
.align div:nth-child(n):nth-child(odd):nth-last-child(2){
    //some css here
}
```

Now this code only selects `:nth-last-child(2)`, i guess because child and last-child can't be used in one selection.

But is there a way to do so?

All anwsers are welcome :P

ps> this is where i got the idea from: [nthmaster](http://nthmaster.com/)

Final Edit,  This was my solution:

```css
.align div:nth-child(n):nth-child(odd):nth-last-child(n+3) {
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="align">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
  <div>11</div>
  <div>12</div>
  <div>13</div>
  <div>14</div>
  <div>15</div>
  <div>16</div>
</div>
```

all i had to do was change `:nth-last-child(2)` to `:nth-last-child(n+3)`

this made the code not only select last child(2) but all child divs from number 2.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: your code select the element that is `nth-last-child(2)` AND is `nth-child(odd)` AND is `nth-child(n)` ... and since `nth-last-child(2)` select only one element so the result is either this element or nothing depending if you meet the other selectors

Comment: What is `:nth-child(n)`  meant to achieve? is that all divs? If so what is the point in having it?

Comment: @Pete yes that selects all divs from the begin, it selects all divs and then selects all odd ones from all divs

Comment: @TemaniAfif so your saying that if i would make the `nth-last-child` select all but the first 2 it would work better?

Comment: remove the nth-child(n) and your selector works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/su6bqpf7/, even works fine with it: http://jsfiddle.net/su6bqpf7/1/.  It's not very clear what you are trying to do though - are you only wanting the second to last child only if it is odd?

Comment: @Pete that's not the result i wanted but, i've managed to fix it using this: `nth-last-child(n+3)` this will select everything but the last 2 and select odd. thanks to @TemaniAfif for giving me an idea of what to do

Comment: Still not clear what you are actually trying to select

Comment: @Pete i wanted to select from all divs, all odd ones and not the last 2 since those are other then the rest in my code, i've made a fiddle to show i this is working, you can create as much divs as you want. all this divs will be selected but never the last 2: `http://jsfiddle.net/p18jgzLh/`

Comment: Could you please attach the code from that fiddle to your question?

Comment: @BoltClock done